# How to use XSL 1.0 to Group Elements by Content

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

so I need to group content using XSL 1.0. In this specific use case, I need to convert the following:

```
<elementFoo name='1'>
    <bar>groupA</bar>
</elementFoo>
<elementFoo name='2'>
    <bar>groupB</bar>
</elementFoo>
<elementFoo name='3'>
    <bar>groupC></bar>
</elementFoo>
<elementFoo name='4'>
    <bar>groupA</bar>
</elementFoo>
<elementFoo name='5'>
    <bar>groupA</bar>
</elementFoo>
<elementFoo name='6'>
    <bar>groupC></bar>
</elementFoo>
```

And I need it to output like this:

Group A:

Foo 1

Foo 4

Foo 5

Group B:

Foo 2

Group C:

Foo 3

Foo 6

Basically, I need to order things according to their content in a specific child element, but I'm not entirely sure how to do this without a bunch of if statements. There can be a large number of groups, and the number of groups is not initially known.

Comment: Read http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml and start following that approach. The key you need is `<xsl:key name="foos-by-bar" match="ElementFoo" use="bar"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

the following `xsl` should group your `foo's` as requested, AND you don't need to bother with pesky `keys`! I modified your `xml` slightly (to add a `root` element, and to fix the name of `groupC`), and made an assumption about how you want your output xml. Let me know if this helps:

#### Source XML

```
<root>
  <elementFoo name='1'>
    <bar>groupA</bar>
  </elementFoo>
  <elementFoo name='2'>
    <bar>groupB</bar>
  </elementFoo>
  <elementFoo name='3'>
    <bar>groupC</bar>
  </elementFoo>
  <elementFoo name='4'>
    <bar>groupA</bar>
  </elementFoo>
  <elementFoo name='5'>
    <bar>groupA</bar>
  </elementFoo>
  <elementFoo name='6'>
    <bar>groupC</bar>
  </elementFoo>
</root>
```

#### XSL Transformation

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="//bar[not(.=preceding::*)]">
        <xsl:variable name="groupName" select="." />
        <xsl:element name="{$groupName}">
            <xsl:for-each select="//elementFoo[bar=$groupName]">
            <foo><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></foo>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

#### Output XML

```
<root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <groupA>
    <foo>1</foo>
    <foo>4</foo>
    <foo>5</foo>
  </groupA>
  <groupB>
    <foo>2</foo>
  </groupB>
  <groupC>
    <foo>3</foo>
    <foo>6</foo>
  </groupC>
</root>
```

A quick explanation:

1. the first `for-each`, iterates over each distinct `bar` value once (i.e. 'groupA', 'groupB', 'groupC')
2. the variable `groupName`, stores the group's name (e.g. 'groupA')
3. the `element` tag, creates an element for the group (e.g.
   `<groupA>`)
4. the second `for-each`, iterates over all `elementFoo's` that have a
   bar value equal to `$groupName`
5. and finally, the `value-of` prints out the `@name` for the current
   `elementFoo`

Simple enough?